# Emacs org-mode: search visible content only, not collapsed?

Tags: search, emacs, tags, org-mode

In Emacs `org-mode`, I sometimes do sparse tree searches to list only headlines that match a tag.

I would like to be able to search only what is currently visible (matching headlines), not the whole buffer as does Isearch. Is this possible natively or via some package?

**Edit:**
As per comment, answered in: [Make isearch skip folded content in `org-mode`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3929/504)

Search behavior can be customized using the `search-invisible` variable, or toggled via `M-s i` during a search.

Comment: See [this](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3929/make-isearch-skip-folded-content-in-org-mode) Emacs StackExchange answer.